# How to record the number of mouse clicks

Tags: java, mouseevent

How to record the number of mouse clicks in Java?

Comment: Please specify what you are trying to do exactly. Also posting some code would be fine. You basically just need to add a new integer variable to the class that receives events and in each mouse click increase its value but without more info I can't be of any more specific help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along the lines of this should do it, Adding the MouseListener on any component you want to listen for clicks on

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements MouseListener{

   /** Number of times the mouse was clicked */
   private int clicks = 0;

   public MyFrame () 
   {
      this.addMouseListener(this);
   }

   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
   { 
       //Increment click count
       clicks++;
   }

   public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
   public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}    
   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)  { }

}
```

Comment: What if I want to count clicks not on a specific element and even not only in my program. I want to count every mouse click just on OS level. Is it possible with Java?

Answer (score 3):

Note that the Java mouse events already have a [click counter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getClickCount%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you would attach a mouse click event handler, and whenever your handler gets called, you would increment an integer counter.